# Can you use blastn to check for exact matches?

Tags: bioinformatics, blast

I need to know on which subjects a query has been matched and where, and this match has to be 100%. Is there a way to do this using blastall?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend asking biostar questions like this, i.e. questions about how to use bioinformatics utilities http://biostar.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't restrict mapping accuracy to 100% but you can increase the stringency on the E value using the `-evalue` argument i.e. use a very very small E value. In addition to that, to return back the subject id or accession number as well as the mapping coordinates you can use a custom output format such as this:

```
-outfmt "6 qacc sacc sseqid evalue qstart qend sstart send"
```

This will return output in tabular format with 8 columns where: `qacc` is the query accession, `sacc` is the subject accession, `sseqid` is the subject seq-id, `evalue` is the E value for the alignment, `qstart` and `qend` are the query start and end mapping coordinates for the alignment and `sstart` and `send` the subject start and end mapping coordinates for the alignment. Putting it all together for an example `blastn` call:

```
blastn -query /path/to/myquery.fasta -db /path/to/db -evalue 0.001 -out /path/to/myoutput.tsv -outfmt "6 qacc sacc sseqid evalue qstart qend sstart send"
```

`blastn -help` will give you more options on the custom output format.